# Count the number of part expressions of an arithmetic expression

Tags: logic, recursion

The problem:

> Define the recursive function numexprs that returns the number of part expressions when given an arithmetic expression. Note that even bool is a part expression.(Individual parentheses are not counted as part expressions.) Evaluate your function on the expression below, and verify that it returns the expected value of 8.
>
> [image]

I don't understand how I should define the recursive function. The question states that I should count the number of part expression in a given arithmetic expression, but the example I'm supposed to verify isn't even an arithmetic expression? I feel very confused.

I was thinking of using something similar to this when defining the function:

[image]

Comment: Count subformulas: every atom ($\text {bool}$) in the example is a subf; every part enclosed between a pair of parentheses is a subf; the formula itself is a subf.

Comment: Something along the line of the inductive def: (i) if $\varphi$ is atomic then $\text {num}(\varphi)=1$; (ii) if $\varphi := (\lnot \psi)$ then $\text {num}(\varphi)=\text {num}(\psi)+1$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's provide indices to the different bool's so we can see better what is going on. OK, so you have the expression:

$((bool_1 \land (bool_2 \lor bool_3)) \land (\neg bool_4))$

The $8$ subexpressions of this expression are:

$bool_1$

$bool_2$

$bool_3$

$bool_4$

$(bool_2 \lor bool_3)$

$(bool_1 \land (bool_2 \lor bool_3))$

$(\neg bool_4)$

$((bool_1 \land (bool_2 \lor bool_3)) \land (\neg bool_4))$

OK, now follow the hint left by Mauro in the Comments